# Disabling Passbook, AppGroups in AppID will affects released version App?

Tags: ios, app-store

I already have released App in AppStore that is using Passbook and AppGroup feature.

And, My client want to remove Passbook and AppGroup feature in new version of App.

So I need to change AppID configuration to disable it.

Will disabling services in AppID configuration affets released current version App?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling Passbook and AppGroup feature will invalidate any provisioning profiles that include the corresponding App ID.

It doesn't effect the existing Appstore apps. However,the associated provisioning profiles must be regenerated for future use.

However, Once you revoke your Apple Push Notification service (APNs) certificate, you will no longer be able to send push notifications to your existing app.

I tried to disable the ApplePay option. It clearly says the above mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I think, disabling "Push Notification" will revoke APNS certificate and it affects released version of App. But any other settings will not affects released version App and affects only provisioning profile.  Is it correct?

Comment: Thank you. I should try to disable each services in AppID configuration and check alert message.

Comment: yeah. that's a nice idea :)